# How do I tell Sidon I've found the land of the sky fish?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

During the story quests "Clues to the Sky" and "Sidon of the Zora", I've been told to let Sidon know if I find clues about a land of the sky fish. I found a waterfall coming from a fish-shaped "Floating Scales Island" east of Sidon I assume is the answer. I swam up the waterfall to the island then went back and talked to Sidon, but nothing happened.

How do I let Sidon know I've found the land of the sky fish (Floating Scales Island)?

[image: Sidon asking about a sky fish]

Comment: As @schaedelkeks wrote in their answer, you have to solve the puzzle. Speaking to Sidon just loops the hint of what you are supposed to do.

Comment: Yeah I also expected to have to talk to Sidon to progress, given I could inform him of the Mark. But no, you're supposed to pay lots of attention to the ancient text, it explains what to do once you have the scales.

Answer (score 3):

He's just repeating the hint. You have to solve the puzzle to progress in the quests. To do so, you have to

> Shoot an arrow fused with a King's Scale at a cluster of rocks that look like a droplet from the 'Land of the Sky Fish'. These rocks are in between the sky fish and East Reservoir Lake.